# How to access email attachments using gmail Contextual Gadget

Tags: php, javascript, openid, imap, gmail-contextual-gadgets

Is there any way to get mail attachments using gmail Contextual Gadget. With extractors it is not possible to read mail attachments.

Comment: Have you looked at the "related" column which contains a question with almost identical wording? [Accessing attachments using gmail contextual gadgets](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3296329)

Comment: @Pekka웃 yup.. those items didn't help. :(

Answer (score 1):

contextual gadgets limitations:

- An extractor can return a maximum of 1,000 characters in each of its output fields.
- Extractors can not read email attachments.

  ```
  source: https://developers.google.com/gmail/contextual_gadgets
  ```

Alternatively you can use IMAP or POP functions https://www.php.net/imap
Or get inspired by reading this post [Downloading attachments to directory with IMAP in PHP, randomly works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649579/downloading-attachments-to-directory-with-imap-in-php-randomly-works)

Comment: If its not possible, then how this gadget fetch attachments from mail: http://get.podio.com/Podio-for-Google-Apps